# Transition for jQuery datatables

Tags: jquery, animation, datatables

When you draw a jQuery datatable, can you have a transition effect so it gets updated in a smooth manner and not instantly?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**That is a real nice question**. I found absolutely no duplicates on SO and no DataTables documentation for that. Additionnally, I used Datatables many times before with lot of customizations and never taught about doing this. **+1 for the idea!** ;)

So what I found is that flexibility to achieve effects on draw depends on how your data is loaded.

If you use an **Ajax source**, you can [defer loading](https://datatables.net/reference/option/deferLoading) for the time you need for an animation.

Below, I made a fadeOut/fadeIn with a blur/unblur effect... Which I'm quite happy of.

I used [preDrawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/preDrawCallback) to blurry and fadeOut all rows. Then used [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) to fadeIn.
I used a CSS class for the blurry effect, which I need to remove using a setTimeout() on drawCallback.

Ho! And I removed the «Processing...» message using the [language](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) option because that was ugly over the animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({

    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
      "url": "https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/scripts/jsonp.php",
      "dataType": "jsonp",
      "deferLoading":600,
    },
    "preDrawCallback": function() {
      $('#example tbody td').addClass("blurry");
      $('#example tbody').fadeOut(600);
    },
    "language": {
      "processing": ""
    },

    "drawCallback": function() {
      $('#example tbody td').addClass("blurry");
      $('#example tbody').fadeIn(800);
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#example tbody td').removeClass("blurry");
      },600);
    }
  });
} );
```

```css
.blurry{
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MBodbq)

---

If you use a **JavaScript array**, the draw cannot be delayed, sadly. The best you can do  on [preDrawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/preDrawCallback) is to hide rows... Because you have no time for an animation here. But on [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback), you are free.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({

    "preDrawCallback": function( settings ) {
      $('#example tbody').hide();
    },

    "drawCallback": function() {
      $('#example tbody td').addClass("blurry");
      $('#example tbody').fadeIn(800);
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#example tbody td').removeClass("blurry");
      },400);
    }
  });
} );
```

```css
.blurry{
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>$345,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>$675,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>$92,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>$357,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiona Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>$850,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shou Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>$163,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>$95,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>$145,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>$235,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>$324,050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>$452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>$136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>$645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Olivia Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>$138,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>$145,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>$356,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lael Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>$103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>$86,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shad Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PBjLyV)

Notice that you have to be careful on your animations timing to avoid the jumpy effect of "no row" displayed. ;)

Comment: @Aenaon please, this is a legit answer